# Bad state: No element, Flutter error. I'm trying to build a scrollable list inside the card. I've attested the screenshot

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here is what I'm trying to build in the form of an image. Please help me, I've spent 7 hours and couldn't find the solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0fNO.jpg)

Here is what I'm getting the error.

The following StateError was thrown building TeamList(dirty, dependencies: [_ModalScopeStatus,
_InheritedProviderScope, _InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#92ce1],
_InheritedProviderScope], state: _TeamListState#fba7a):
Bad state: No element

The relevant error-causing widget was:
TeamList file:///E:/Flutter%20Projects/mobile%20app%2013/lib/Screens/TeamModule.dart:91:27

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      ListMixin.firstWhere (dart:collection/list.dart:167:5)
#1      ProjectProvider.chatById (package:vstudio/Providers/ProjectProvider.dart:309:26)
#2      _TeamListState.build (package:vstudio/widgets/TeamList.dart:35:49)

Here is my code

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:vstudio/Screens/AddTeamMember.dart';
import '../Providers/auth.dart';
import '../Providers/ProjectProvider.dart';
import '../Screens/ChatScreens/IndividualPage.dart';
import '../models/ChatModel/ChatModel.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class TeamList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? pId;
  String? userId;
  String? name;

  final String? email;
  String profession = 'Script Writer';

  TeamList(
    this.pId,
    this.userId,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.profession,
  );

  @override
  _TeamListState createState() => _TeamListState();
}

class _TeamListState extends State<TeamList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ChatModel sourchat = Provider.of<Auth>(context).sourceChatUser;
    final ChatModel? chatModel = (sourchat.id != widget.userId)
        ? Provider.of<ProjectProvider>(context).chatById(widget.userId)
        : sourchat;

    final projectId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String?;

    return Dismissible(
      key: ValueKey(widget.email),
      background: Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).errorColor,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.delete,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 40,
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 4,
        ),
      ),
      direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
      confirmDismiss: (direction) {
        return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Are you sure?'),
            content: Text(
              'Do you want to remove the team member?',
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: Text('No'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(ctx).pop(false);
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Yes'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(ctx).pop(true);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        Provider.of<ProjectProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .removeTeamMember(widget.pId, widget.email);
      },
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 15,
          vertical: 4,
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          child: ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: FittedBox(
                  child: Text(widget.name![0].toUpperCase()),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            title: Text(
              widget.name!,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
            subtitle: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'profession: Scriptwriter',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
                Text(widget.email.toString(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
              ],
            ),
            trailing:
                widget.userId != chatModel!.id || widget.userId != sourchat.id
                    ? IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.message),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (contex) => IndividualPage(
                                        chatModel: chatModel,
                                        sourchat: sourchat,
                                      )));
                        })
                    : IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                        onPressed: () => {
                              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                                  AddTeamMember.rounteName,
                                  arguments: projectId),
                            }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the code at `TeamModule.dart:91:27`?

Answer (score 1):

You using firstWhere method in some code, maybe in chatById method inside the provider,

you can avoid this exception by adding **orElse** param as the following:

`list.firstWhere((a) => a == b, orElse: () => null);`